# If I move my capital in CK2 will I take my technology with me?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm currently playing as the king of Eire in Charlemagne and I am around 150 years in. I've started to expand into England and will soon hold all the southern counties. With the bonus of the additional holdings I was considering changing my capital from Dublin to Middlesex and my duchies to Essex and Kent.

The only downside I can see is my technology in Dublin (e.g., legalism etc.) is currently higher than in Middlesex. Will the technology transfer or will I lose it and adopt the technology levels that Middlesex currently has?

Are there any other disadvantages to moving my capital that I've not considered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your capital moves to Middlesex, you will use Middlesex's technology levels.

However, you will keep any technology points you haven't spent, and can spend them in Middlesex after the move. If you spend some time saving them, you'll be able to give Middlesex a technology boost when you arrive.